# In App Audio calling in android and IOS

Tags: android, ios, android-studio, sip, voip

I am searching for correct information about implementing In **app calling** using **SIP** and **VoIP**.But I am not getting correct source of information for this and even I am confused about where to start.

Is there any SDK or Tutorial available for android ?

Comment: Have a look on : Twilio - www.twilio.com

Comment: check this out : https://tokbox.com/platform/sip-interconnect